# Configure Apache with multiple ProxyPass and different ports

Tags: apache, web, mod-proxy, proxypass

so i have a config file that states this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.aaaaaaaa.yyyyyyyyy.co.uk
  ServerAlias aaaaaaa.yyyyyyy.co.uk
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.aaaaaaa.yyyyyyyyy.co.uk [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =aaaaaa.yyyyyyyyy.co.uk
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.xxxxxx.yyyyyyyy.co.uk
  ServerAlias xxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.co.uk
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8989/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8989/
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.xxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyy.co.uk [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =xxxxxx.yyyyyyyyyy.co.uk
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

when visiting aaaaaaa.yyyyyyyyy.co.uk it redirects to https which is the desiered effect and launches the correct app.

however when i visit xxxxx.yyyyyyy.co.uk it shows the correct app but does not redirect to https, when i physically type https://xxxx.yyyyyy.co.uk it redirects me to the same app as aaaaaaa.yyyyyyyyyy.co.uk.

how can i make this work!

Comment: Does anything change if you use `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{SERVER_NAME}`?

Comment: no change at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is certbot dosn't play nice with multiple hosts in 1 file.

The steps to correct the problem where;

1 remove all certificates

2 recreate all virtual hosts in there own file within sites-availible
  (minus the rewrite portion)

example content of one conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.aaaaaaaa.yyyyyyyyy.co.uk
  ServerAlias aaaaaaa.yyyyyyy.co.uk
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

3 after doing this for all virtual hosts (sites) run the command

```
certbot --apache
```

and create new certificates for all making sure to select the redirect function at the end.

worked great!